# Как перевести символ из строки в число с помощью atoi

Tags: c, char

Следующий код не компилируется:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{
    char str[] = "123456789";
    printf("str: %s\n", str);

    int two = atoi(str[1]);
    printf("two: %i\n", two);
}
```

Компилятор пишет:

```
 warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion
      passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with
      & [-Wint-conversion]
        int two = atoi(str[1]);
```

Если поставить `&` перед `atoi`, компилируется, но он переводит всю строку, начиная с `str[1]` в число. Как мне перевести в число только один символ из строки - `str[1]`?

Comment: С помощью atoi только так: создать новую строку длины 1, скопировать туда нужный символ и передать в `atoi`. Функция atoi принимает СТРОКУ. Либо проще. 1 символ - это 1 цифра, тогда str[1]-'0' и будет этой цифрой.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, больше спасибо! Оформите Ваш комментарий, как ответ, чтобы я мог принять его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью atoi только так: создать новую строку длины 1, скопировать туда нужный символ и передать в atoi. Функция atoi принимает СТРОКУ. Либо проще. 1 символ - это 1 цифра, тогда `str[1]-'0'` и будет этой цифрой

Answer (score 4):

Так посмотрите на протиотип:

```
int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

Функция принимает указатель на строку (`char *`), а вы подсовываете ей символ (`char`). Потому и не компилируется.

А перевести в число один символ (при условии что он является десятичной цифрой) очень просто:

```
int two = str[1] - '0';
```